# If i subscribe one email list on another, do the messages cycle forever?

Tags: email, smtp

If i subscribe one email list on another, do the messages cycle forever?
why not?

Comment: Why are you even asking this? If you did create some kind of loop, did you really think the admin wouldn't notice something funky in the mail queue?

Answer (score 2):

That depends entirely on the mailing list software.  Mailman puts in a header to detect loops, but if the other mailing list is not Mailman, it may strip it off and prevent it from working.